# Unable to grab custom type from get_post_meta

Tags: php, wordpress

```
$wp_query = new WP_Query([
    'post_type' => 'office',
    'post_status' => 'any',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
]);

$offices = [];
if (count($wp_query->posts) > 0) {
    $offices = $wp_query->posts;
}

foreach ($offices as $office) {
    $office = get_post_meta($wp_query, '_office_id');
    print_r($office);
}
```

Could someone tell me why I'm not receiving any results from my `get_post_meta`? I'm not sure if I'm using the `$wp_query` call inside the function correctly. the `_office_id` definitely exists and I have used it before `using get_the_ID`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `get_post_meta()` function takes a `$post_ID` as first argument.

In your example code, try using the `$office->ID`. For example:

```
foreach ($offices as $office) {
    $office_id = get_post_meta($office->ID, '_office_id', true);
    print_r($office_id);
}
```

Also, note that I have set the third argument of the function to `true` as it seems that the code is expecting only one value. If the code is expecting a list of values, then change it back to `false` (or remove it).

Reference: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the answer by using the following call:

`$office = get_post_meta($office->ID, '_office_id', true);`